# Css transition in Opera

Tags: css, transition, opera

I have a css-transition-animation which works in all Browsers but Opera:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = function(){

  if(document.getElementById('box').className == 'small'){
    document.getElementById('box').className = '';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('box').className = 'small';
  }

}
```

```css
#box {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 1036px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 265px;
    opacity:1;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}
#box.small {
    height:0px;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button>Make small</button>
```

When I add the class `small` the box-height should be set to zero while drift into `opacity:0`.This works fine but not in Opera.

I wonder if this comes from defining `all` and later `opacity`. Is this not allowed? Or has his problem another reason?

PS: Opera 12.16, win32

PPS: Well - looks like it was the Opera version. But all other transitions on this page worked. Why?

PPS: As mentioned in the comments I changed `all` with `height` to test it and voilà it works. Thx for the clarification and the input!

Comment: See [this website?](http://caniuse.com/). It helps a lot for stuff like this. What version of opera are we talking?

Comment: @jbutler483 - sorry forgot about that. Added!

Comment: If it's the `all`, then you could test by changing it to `height 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.1s ease-out;`

Comment: And it should be fine to use `all` first, per spec : "If a property is specified multiple times in the value of ‘transition-property’ (either on its own, via a shorthand that contains it, or via the ‘all’ value), then the transition that starts uses the duration, delay, and timing function at the index corresponding to the *last* item in the value of ‘transition-property’ that calls for animating that property."

Comment: Just for your information, the code in question as-is works exactly as required in Opera 26, so it might be some gap in implementation which was fixed in later releases.

Comment: @Harry: It's less a "gap in implementation" and more of a "new engine" case (Presto replaced by Blink after Opera 12). Fuzzyma: Rather than adding to your question what you did to get it to work, why not write an answer with your solution yourself, and then accept it? That way, someone with a similar problem can benefit from it later; as it stands, they'd have to read your PPS to learn there even was a solution and your question will still appear as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem occures because of the Opera Version.
In `Opera 12.16` the `all`, `opacity`-case is handled wrong. To make it work you have to specify every property you want to animate.
With `Opera 26` it works all fine.

This is a good example where you cant relie on the full/correct implementation of prefixed features. Make sure you test every use case when using it anyway.

Thanks to the comments on the question which helped me solving the issue!